# How do I (successfully) set a maskView to a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, mask

I'm making a camera-based app and would like to make a frosted overlay on the camera preview, with a rounded rectangle cut out from the frosted view.

I've been trying to achieve this with the maskLayer of UIView, introduced with iOS 8 and have been wildly unsuccessful.

Here's what my code currently looks like:

```
// Blur the preview
UIBlurEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIView *blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view insertSubview:blurView aboveSubview:imagePicker.view];

// Make blur view fill screen
{
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[blurView]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[blurView]-0-|"
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(blurView)]];
}

// Add a rounded of transparency to the blurView  **not working**
UIView *mask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.f, 50.f, 50.f, 50.f)];
mask.alpha = 1.0f;
mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[blurView setMaskView:mask]; // Remove this line, and everything is frosted.  Keeping this line and nothing is frosted.
```

As my comments indicate, adding the mask removes the frosted view completely (changing the opacity of the mask does nothing).  I know that this won't create the effect I'm looking for (it should only be frosted in that rectangle), but I can't get the maskView to work in any capacity.

Comment: Last line of code contains mistake. Try: [blurView setMaskView:mask];

Comment: @ninjaproger That was an error in my post (now corrected).  Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Answer (score 6):

The UIView api says

> An optional view whose alpha channel is used to mask a view’s
>   content.

The best way to see this is to use a UIImageView loaded with an RGBA image that sports an alpha channel - a PNG exported with transparency switched on from photoshop will do it. And then resize, with the origin set to 0,0.

A second way to do it would be to create a UIView, with no alpha i.e. `[UIColor clearColor]` and add a subview which has an alpha `[UIColor whiteColor];`

```
UIView *mask = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,100,100}];
mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *areaToReveal = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){20,20,50,50}];
areaToReveal.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[mask addSubview:areaToReveal];
_myView.maskView = mask;
```

You could add further UIViews which are translucent by x amount using `[UIColor colorFromRed: green: blue: alpha:x];`

Comment: It would be more correct if you add the [UIColor whiteColor] to the code as it based on the default behavior of the new UIView, which could be problem when Apple decides to change it. Anyway it's correct.